# Dynamic Bot Framework Composer dialog to turn any PVA list into a vertical one or Bot Canvas

Tags: arrays, bot-framework-composer, power-platform, power-virtual-agents

I am currently working on a dialog in Composer that would let me turn all my lists in PVA vertical by calling it and passing 3-5 strings used to form the list. I am however a little stuck, my first issue is that the inputs I'd like to provide to the dialog through the dialog interface input option do not seem to actually come up as a variable in the dialog itself, see the picture for clarity. [Picture of Composer Dialog Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO1A6.png)

We have around 250 topics in our PVA bot now, and it therefore wouldn't really do to 'hardcode' the options in for every list we have. I could live with having 3-5 dialogs based on the amount of inputs if that is a limiting factor (I am not sure if we have to use all the input strings per se for example, or if we can omit empty ones.

What I'd like to do is make an empty array, and then push the strings provided to the dialog from PVA which will then form the list: [Composer array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlzyM.png)

But the variables I passed in the dialogue interface are not showing up as options in the dialog creation itself.

I know I can access PVA variables by making them global, but I'd like to go a little more beyond that.

So, in PVA, decide what strings to pass to Composer, use these to make a vertical list and pass this back, and make sure that the composer steps are dynamic so that I can re-use this list-making dialog in any of the places where I need a vertical list.

I've also seen recommendations of just using CSS/HTML templates if you want /all/ your lists to be vertical (which I do), I just can't find more information about that, just: https://powervirtualagents.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/change-your-power-virtual-agents-default-canvas-bot-icon-and-name/

Any suggestions on whether this is a painstaking route I am trying to take through Composer, and any success using the canvases/HTML instead?

Kind regards
Niels